# Is it pissible to login using Cognito Social Login without a hosted UI?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I'm using `react-google-login` and `amazon-cognito-identity-js` packages to log my users in.

I'd like to use the `amazon-cognito-identity-js`'s auth method, passing the user's email and password, to call Cognito functions and set the tokens to local storage.

However, coming to Cognito Social Login, it is only possible to use this URI: `https://doamin.auth.us-region.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000`.

On clicking the URL, it redirects to call back url. Can i make this process like amazon-cognito-identity-js authenticate method?